# File path in HTML doc not locating CSS file

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing issues with a HTML document located in a folder (in root dir) not being able to reference a CSS file located in another folder (in the same root dir). The same issue also applies in the file explorer in Windows no matter what I do although IE for a change seems to show success!

I have used everything from "/" to "../../" and everything in-between, but nothing seems to work! Images are showing up fine in the HTML document in question, using "..//" but the CSS nor JS folders are being accessed.

The file structure is as follows:

```
*********
ROOT DIR
*********
/CSS/style.css
/SERV/serv.html
index.html
```

When referencing the folders in the serv.html what file path should I use and if I've used it already WTH is going on?

The Code:

```
<head>
<title>blah </title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/config.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-desktop.css" />
</noscript>
</head>
```

Thanks in advance, I have spent a good few hours searching the net and even longer trying out different file paths.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to access and from what?

Comment: I'm trying to access the CSS formatting stored in the CSS file which is located in a folder called "CSS" and the Javascript in a folder called "JS" on the serv.html page. I'm using firefox 27.0.1 - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to `style.css` from `index.html`:

```
"CSS/style.css"
```

The path to `style.css` from `serve.html`:

```
"../CSS/style.css"
```

If you have another folder called `JS` in your root directory, you access it the same way but replacing the names obviously. This should clear up how the path works.

Links should always be put in the head of your html file as such:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link/>
        <link/>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Links inside `noscript` tags are used for browsers that have script disabled. According to [this source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp), when including `noscript` tags in your `head` section, you must also put `link`, `meta`, and `style` elements.

Comment: Still no luck, I had tried "../" already. Here's an example of the code in the serv.html file:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />

It's in the head!!

Comment: @StuartClarke If your pathways are right then something else in your code is wrong. Are you sure filenames are spelled the way you think they are, IDs are identified by `#` and classes by `.` in your css file?

Comment: I'm sure, at least the index.html under the root dir is working fine which is why this is driving me a bit crazy!

Comment: Ok so you have your main folder.. Inside of that folder is your index.html and a JS, CSS, and SERV folder, correct? Then inside of each one of those is the .js, .css, and serv.html file?

Comment: Ok, it seems I have found the issue! I had the css reference links in a <noscript> tag, this doesnt seems to cause a problem for the index.html but is an issue when the html file is in a sub folder, any idea why that might be? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah! Yes, link tags should always be in the `head` of your html file. For example: *updated answer for more space*

Comment: But this is all within the <head> tags, ie in between the aforementioned and the closing </head> tag. What I dont understand is that the index.html shows up fine but when moved to a folder it doesnt work!

Comment: I don't know why it worked differently, but you should never put those link tags anywhere than directly inside the head tags.

Comment: <head>
<title>blah </title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
</noscript>
</head>

This is what I have done!

Comment: Yeah so the <noscript> tags are for browsers that don't have script enabled and thus show alternate content. Just make sure the links are directly inside your head tags and you should be fine. This discussion has become too long. I hope I have answered your question to your satisfaction.

Comment: I have added the full code to the OP to save confusion, as long as I can include the css links without the noscript tags then Im happy, Im relatively new to this so dont know the tricks of the trade. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Removing the no script tags causes issues with the formatting on mobile devices so I still need to fix this if possible!

Comment: Try keeping the noscript the way it was and duplicate the css link to outside the noscript tags but still inside the header